# Return a render to a view from another function in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am making a simple web page. I have to ask for an input, define its type, make some processing and return a few values.
I have two views, one that has a simple form asking for an input, and the other one:

```
def processedframe(request):
    frame = request.POST['frame']
    try: 
        if frame.startswith('>RUS08'):        
            try:
                # Frame procesing(a lot)
                return render(request, 'frame.html', {'values': values)
            except:
                return HttpResponse("Processing error")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid frame")
    except:
        return HttpResponse("Invalid input")
```

The problem is that i have +30 frame types with diferent things to process.
I want to make one extern function in other folder for each frame type, and return a render from the function.

I have already tried to make a separate folder with the functions and import it into the views.py
That worked fine, because it was able to enter to the frame processing for the function, but when i tried to return the render from the function, i got an error, because the views.py was not returning anything.
I have also tried to render from the views.py but i was not able to acces to the values from the function.

I have also tried putting the code to process the frame inside the processedframe function

```
try:
     # HERE
      return render(request, 'frame.html', {'values': values)
```

and that is working fine, but as there a lot of lines of code, and i have to process a lot of diferent frame types, i want to take it to other part.

Has anybody donde something similar?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do something like a decorator, so:

```
def frame_processor(prefix, template_name='frame.html'):
    def decorator(func):
        def processedframe(request, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                frame = request.POST['frame']
                assert frame.startswith(prefix)
                try:
                    return render(
                        request,
                        template_name,
                        {'values': func(request, frame, *args, **kwargs)},
                    )
                except:
                    return HttpResponse('Processing error', status_code=500)
            except (KeyError, AssertionError):
                return HttpResponse('Invalid frame', status_code=400)
            except:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid input', status_code=400)

        return processedframe

    return decorator
```

Then you can decorate a view with:

```
@frame_processor('>RUS08')
def my_view(request, frame):
    # determine value
    return value
```